# Is there a command to keep the iPhone camera recording?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Basically, I have an idea for my App, I would like the iPhone camera to keep recording a video even when the user is doing something else (like checking twitter, for example) like a spy cam. I have many coding solutions available

Is there a way I can code this with either HTML5 ,CSS, javascript or xcode?

Comment: If it's an iPhone app, you will need to learn Swift, apple's programming language. Xcode is just the software used to make the app, not the actual programming language...

Comment: You can download one of the already designed apps, but this could only work when you have your phone jailbroken. I don't recommend doing that, but if it's important for you, you could first jailbroke your iphone and then search for a good spy cam @ cydia.

Comment: @NathanParker Hmmm, What if i searched for some decent source code?

Answer (score 1):

iOS will not allow you to run the camera constantly in the background. This is because once each app enters the background state, it only has a very short time to wrap-up it's processes and prepare to be suspended (iOS does this to conserve memory).

From the [apple developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)

> In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
>
>   - Apps that record audio content while in the background
>   - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as    a navigation app
>   - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>   - Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
>   - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

The only other way to achieve what you want is to jailbreak your device and distribute your app on Cydia (the jailbroken App Store). Jailbreaking will free your device from the restrictions of IOS but will also make your phone a lot more vulnerable to being hacked...

Comment: •Apps that need to download and process new content regularly That;s exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: Great!, just make sure you follow the guidelines linked to in my answer in order to allow iOS to give you background access...